# How to deal with ChromeDriver for Selenium producing core dumps?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I have a *Python* program working with *Chrome* browser on my *Linux* server, and sometimes it raises the error in the lines of `max retries exceeded`, which makes the browser unoperable for some reason (cannot even get the page source). This is fine because in this case I can just do `driver.stop()` and restart it from scratch. Hoever, at some point `core.xxx` files start appearing in the directory of the programe and quickly fill up all the memory that I have for the project. Additionally, I have noticed after a few hours of running a bunch of proceses like these still running:

```
root     32701  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    12:38   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
root     32702  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [cat] <defunct>
root     32703  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [cat] <defunct>
root     32704  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
root     32705  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
root     32707  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [chrome_crashpad] <defunct>
```

So, the question is: How do I stop the core dumps from appearing and how to remove those prosecces, because my current setup maxes out both the disk space and RAM.

Comment: Maybe follow the steps shown in this article: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-core-dumps-in-linux-with-systemd-sysctl/. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These error running processes...

```
root     32701  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    12:38   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
root     32702  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [cat] <defunct>
root     32703  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [cat] <defunct>
root     32704  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
root     32705  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
root     32707  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    09:43   0:00 [chrome_crashpad] <defunct>
```

...it seems you are executing your tests as a ***`root`*** user.

---

### *Thumb rule*

> *A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

---

### Solution

An immediate solution would be to execute your test as a ***`non-root`*** / ***`non-admin`*** user.

---

### Outro

As per the documentation in [**ChromeDriver crashes**](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/help/chromedriver-crashes?authuser=0) to diagnose/fix ChromeDriver crashes there are a few options. On windows, you wll see the popup:

[image: chromedriver_stopped_working]

In these cases you have two options:

- [Create a repro case](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/help/chromedriver-crashes?authuser=0#h.p_ID_55): Create a repro case in [WebDriver for GoogleChrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list) so that ChromeDriver contributors can use to reproduce and debug the problem.
- [Get a dump of the crash (windows only)](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/help/chromedriver-crashes?authuser=0#h.p_ID_59): To create and debug a crash dump, you need a debug version of ChromeDriver. You can check out Chrome sources and build the debug version of ChromeDriver. When the crash happens, attach the debugger and observe what is happening.

  Configure your system to create a fulldump on crash. [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section contains the detailed steps.

  After a crash dump is created, use WinDbg to analyze it:

  `<ctrl-d>` and choose dump file

  ```
  .sympath+ SRV*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;D:\path\to\directory\containing\pdb
  !sym noisy      # just to show any problems we have finding symbols
  ld chromedriver    # or !reload
  lmvm chromedriver    # Should show chromedriver has private/debug symbols
  !analyze -v    # Tells windbg to analyze the exception
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[How to disable core dumps in Linux including systemd](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-core-dumps-in-linux-with-systemd-sysctl/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already use the `--no-sandbox` flag, so it doesn't seem like this is the issue here. Nonetheless, could you, please, clarify how to run chrome as non-root in python?

Comment: Read the finer prints: _it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag_ but not obivious.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. That is why I am asking how to run it as non-root just like you suggested.